# Software support for GML 3.3 Linear Referencing?

Tags: gml, linear-referencing, ogc

Are you aware of any software supporting import/export of Linear Referencing data in GML version 3.3 format?

Apparently no software application, proprietary or FOSS, currently supports it explicitly.  I've read elsewhere that "GML 3.3 is itself a GML 3.2.1 application schema".  So maybe software applications that support version 3.2.1 already implicitly support GML 3.3.  Yet that does not necessarily mean the correct bindings for LRS reading/writing have actually been implemented.  Please let me know otherwise.

Comment: I didn't even find GML 3.3 sample files illustrating Linear Referencing capabilities.  I've only found some snippets in the OGC GML 3.3 specification: Annex A (informative) — Linear referencing method examples: https://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=46568

Comment: I've found a more complete example in Annex B, "Sample XML (Informative)", of OGC 16-104r2, "OGC InfraGML 1.0: Part 4 – LandInfra Roads - Encoding Standard", especially section B.1, "Complete Road (less Cross Sections) XML":
https://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=75121